# What's a good observable appendable base for a TextArea?

Tags: javafx

I have a `StringBuffer` that is occasionally appended with new information.

In a separate module, I have a JavaFX `TextArea` that displays that `StringBuffer`.

Right now, I have to manually update the `TextArea` every time the underlying data is modified.

Is there something like an `ObservableList` (which I use for TableViews) that I can use as the back-end data for the `TextArea` instead, so I don't have to manually manage pushing the changes to the display?

I am not attached to using a `StringBuffer`. I'm glad to use any appendable data structure to hold text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider something simple like this:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;

public class ObservableStringBuffer extends StringBinding {

    private final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer() ;

    @Override
    protected String computeValue() {
        return buffer.toString();
    }


    public void set(String content) {
        buffer.replace(0, buffer.length(), content);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void append(String text) {
        buffer.append(text);
        invalidate();
    }

    // wrap other StringBuffer methods as needed...

}
```

This enables easy coding for binding to a text area. You can simply do

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
ObservableStringBuffer buffer = new ObservableStringBuffer();
textArea.textProperty().bind(buffer);

// ...

buffer.append("Hello world");
```

However, it's important to note here that you don't transfer the efficiency of the buffer API to the text area: the text area simply has a `textProperty()` representing its text, which can still only really be modified by `set(...)` and `setValue(...)`. In other words, when you append to the buffer, you essentially end up with `textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "Hello world")` (not `textArea.appendText("Hello world")`. If you're just looking for a clean API, then this should work for you; if you're looking for something efficient, you would have to "wire" the calls to `appendText` yourself, since that is simply not supported by the text area's `textProperty()`.

Here's a SSCCE using the above class:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ObservableStringBufferTest extends Application {

    private int counter ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableStringBuffer buffer = new ObservableStringBuffer();

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.textProperty().bind(buffer);

        buffer.set("Item 0");

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(1), 
                e -> buffer.append("\nItem "+(++counter))));

        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(textArea)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```